# React states remain undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set the `in` property of a bootstrap `<Collapse>` tag to true on a button click. But when I try to reference my `is_open` state its undefined.

```
class Graph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super (props);

  this.state = ({
      is_open: false,
  });
 }
  
 click_open = () => {
     console.log(this.is_open); // logs undefined
     this.setState({ is_open: !this.is_open });
 }


 render() {
     return (
          <div className='container>
              <button onClick={this.click_open}>TAB</Button>
              <Collapse in={this.is_open}></Collapse>
          </div>
     )
 })
}
```

No matter what I do my state stays undefined. What am I missing here?

Comment: You may be confused because of a typo. to access state, `this.state.is_open` instead of `this.is_open`?

Comment: use `this.state.is_open` to access state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `state`

Change your code to be:

```js
 click_open = () => {
     console.log(this.state.is_open);
     this.setState({ is_open: !this.is_open });
 }
```

Comment: This should have been a comment. Issues caused by typo should be voted closed.